# Need to figure out xpath to get sibling node

Tags: xpath

I have to return a certain node that is a sibling to a node that I am using to select a certain parent of both nodes...

suppose...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<dataTemplateSpecification id="id1" name="name1">
<templates xmlns="">
<template>
  <elements>
    <element id="element0" name="PatientId" display="Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="32">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/PATIENT_ID" />
      <validation>
        <rules>
          <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
            <fail>
              <html>
                <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
              </html>
            </fail>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </validation>
    </element>
    <element id="element4" name="Active" display="ACTIVE" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" value="A">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/ACTIVE" />
      <!--//Templates/Patient/sources/source/empi"/>-->
      <validation>
        <rules>
          <rule id="r1" test="#element1.value == ''">
            <fail>
              <html>
                <b>EMPI ID is null, value must be present</b>
              </html>
            </fail>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </validation>
    </element>
    <element id="element2" name="PopulationPatientID" display="Population Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" enc="223" value="198">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID" />
      <!--Patient/compositeID[./idType='populationPatientID']/id-->
      <validation>
        <rules>
          <rule id="r1" test="#element1.value == ''">
            <fail>
              <html>
                <b>EMPI ID is null, value must be present</b>
              </html>
            </fail>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </validation>
    </element>
    <element id="element1" name="EncounterId" display="Encounter ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="223">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/FOCUSED_READMISSIONS_ID" />
      <validation>
        <rules>
          <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
            <fail>
              <html>
                <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
              </html>
            </fail>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </validation>
    </element>
```

The Xpath I have right now currently only gets the right template.  But I need the right element...

```
//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template[./elements/element[@name="PopulationPatientID" and @value="198" and @enc="223"]]
```

I need to xpath to the node that has an attribute named "Active"  Is that even possible?  I was thinking I might need to drill backwords in the [] section... you know [./../../] where I would be selecting by a finer granularity before then... //dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[./../../] ect.. Does that make sense or am I completely rambling here?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a little confusing. There is no attribute named "Active" in the XML document (some end tags are missing, by the way). But there is a `name` attribute with the value "Active". If you want to select the element with that attribute, then what about simply `//element[@name="Active"]`?

Comment: The value of the attribute name is "Active": name="Active"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@royerboat and @Dimitre Novatchev...

both of you guys had the right idea and it inspired me to get the Xpath that I needed...

```
//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template[./elements/element[@name="PopulationPatientID" and @value="198" and @enc="223"]]//element[@name = 'Active']
```

That xpath is precisely what I need.  Dimitre, I tried both of your sugestions and they came close, but no cigar.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the template instead of the element with your XPath search is because you are searching for template.

//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template[./elements/element[@name="PopulationPatientID" and @value="198" and @enc="223"]]

If you want the element instead, you need to specify it before the predicate part of the XPath statement (the predicate being the part in [ ] or brackets).

Also, if you are looking for the element with the **name** attribute that has a value of "Active", you can specify it as part of your XPath statement.

Either one of the following statements will get the element with that has a name of "Active":

```
/dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[@name = 'Active']

//element[@name = 'Active']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/*/*/element
          [@name="PopulationPatientID" and @value="198" and @enc="223"]
            /preceding-sibling::element[1]
```

**or even simpler**:

```
/*/*/*/*/element[@name='Active']
```

Comment: @royerboat and ... 
The preceding-sibling::element[1] is what i am looking for.  The Xml will have multiple Active elements.  I need to pick the right Template that has the right Active element.

Comment: @DmainEvent: I am glad my answer was useful. Could you, please, consider accepting the best answer?